# Why does the childNodes array have and inaccurate number of items

Tags: javascript, xml

As you can see from the image below, the childNodes array has 13 item. But clearly the "book" element has only 6 childNodes. Why is this inaccurate?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: An element is not the same thing as a node. Text also counts as nodes. So do comments and a few other things.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_childnodes.asp

Answer (score 2):

Because `childNodes` returns all child nodes, including text nodes (even if they contain only whitespace).  If you iterate the child nodes and output their `nodeType` you will see that some are elements and some are text.